# Responsive footer CSS issue

Tags: wordpress, css

I have a wordpress website at http://amcham.konsagous.com/
The footer looks good on desktop, however on the Mobile you there is a Social Media links DIV that doesn't moves.
Also the copyright footer doesn't moves down in the mobile view. I tried the following :

```
.site-info{
position : absolute;
bottom : 0px;
}
```

But then the footer vanished. Any suggestions in this ?

Comment: If you want to always sticking to the bottom of the screen:
`.site-info{ position : fixed; bottom : 0px; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hi Remove in line style its look good for responsive design.

```
text-2 
{
 position: absolute; - remove
}
text-3
{
position: absolute; - remove
top: 325px; - remove
}
text-4
{
position: absolute;  - remove
    top: 593px;  - remove
}
text-5
{
position: absolute;  - remove
top: 847px; - remove
}
```

aside#text-5
{
 position: absolute !important; - remove
}